# Parsing Solr status response XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, solr, jaxb, unmarshalling

Solr returns status information in the following XML form (this is a shortened version):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">2</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

I'd like to pull this into my Java application. I created the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    @XmlElement(name="lst")
    private ResponseHeader responseHeader;

    public ResponseHeader getResponseHeader() {
        return responseHeader;
    }

    public void setResponseHeader(ResponseHeader responseHeader) {
        this.responseHeader = responseHeader;
    }

    public Response() {}
}
```

for the root element, and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseHeader {

    @XmlElement(name="int")
    private IntegerElement status;

    @XmlElement(name="int")
    private IntegerElement QTime;

    ....

}
```

for the code inside. Finally, there's this for the int fields:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IntegerElement implements Serializable {

@XmlTransient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlAttribute
protected String name;

@XmlValue
private int value;

    ...

}
```

When I try to unmarshal the piece of xml above, only one of the int elements is filled. The other doesn't get set (i.e. null). No errors though. How should I go about annotating these classes better?

A longer piece of the XML is this:

```
  <lst name="index">
    <int name="numDocs">0</int>
    <int name="maxDoc">0</int>
    <int name="deletedDocs">0</int>
    <long name="version">1</long>
    <int name="segmentCount">0</int>
    <bool name="current">true</bool>
    <bool name="hasDeletions">false</bool>
    <str name="directory">org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory:NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/home/marceau/Developer/Servers/solr/example/solr/collection1/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@22bda240; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)</str>
    <lst name="userData" />
    <long name="sizeInBytes">65</long>
    <str name="size">65 bytes</str>
  </lst>
```

I've adapted Benoit Wickramarachi sample with inheritance to produce this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="lst")
public class Index {

@XmlElementWrapper( name = "lst" )
@XmlElements( { 
    @XmlElement( name="int", type = IntegerElement.class ),
    @XmlElement( name="str", type = StringElement.class),
    @XmlElement( name="bool", type = BooleanElement.class),
    @XmlElement( name="date", type = DateElement.class),
    @XmlElement( name="long", type = LongElement.class),
    @XmlElement( name="lst", type = ListElement.class)
    } )
private List<ResponseElement> index;

public Index() {}
```

The unmarshalling process doesn't crash, but it merely creates an Index object containing an ArrayList named index that is completely empty (10 nulls in debugger, size 0).

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to support this use case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseHeader {

    @XmlPath("int[1]")
    private IntegerElement status;

    @XmlPath("int[2]")
    private IntegerElement QTime;

    ....

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

Change the lines:

```
@XmlElement(name="int")
private IntegerElement status;

@XmlElement(name="int")
private IntegerElement QTime;
```

to:

```
@XmlElement(name="int")
private List<IntegerElement> intElements;
```

So that all `int` element would be unmarshalled in a List.

Then to get values iterate over the list:

```
for(IntegerElement intEl : intElements){
    System.out.println(intEl.getName() + " = " + intEl.getValue());
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use Inheritance in Jaxb, use the following annotations (`IElement` behing the interface implemented by `IntegerElement` and `StringElement`):

```
@XmlElementWrapper( name = "lst" )
@XmlElements( { 
    @XmlElement( name="int", type = IntegerElement.class ),
    @XmlElement( name="str", type = StringElement.class)
    } )
private List<IElement> elements;
```

Comment: I'm liking this, and it works. I just realized though that my sample may have been too easy. There are other elements mixed in there as well. I'm using a superclass ResponseElement, and then we have StringElement, LongElement, ... Then in ResponseHeader, I can have List<ResponseElement>. But the question would then be: how can I combine these various types into a single List member and have JAXB correctly unmarshal xml? Example xml:
    `<lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <str name="name">collection1</str>
    </lst>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've added some example xml and code to my main post. I'm hoping you could take a look at it.

Comment: Have you registered all classes in the JaxbContext?  JAXBContext.newInstance(IntegerElement.class, StringElement.class,...);

Comment: I had Index.class in there by itself, initially. Other classes are annotated with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="long")
public class LongElement extends ResponseElement`. However, even after adding them all to the static factory method, I still get the same empty list.

Comment: Each sub-class need to be annotate with @XmlRootElement( name = "int" ) etc... I just found a good example on inheritance http://peter-braun.org/2013/01/inheritance-when-using-jaxb/ that could help you.